# как получить текст после символа?

Tags: python

дан текст:

```
text = 'нужно получить текст до символа/и после символа'
```

нужно получить текст до /  и после
как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

используйте метод `split`

```
print(text.split("/"))
```

Comment: огромное вам спасибо, вы очень помогли

Answer (score 3):

если у вас в тексте только один разделитель, то можно использовать функцию `split`

```
part1, part2 = text.split('/')
```

если разделителей в строке много, тогда сформируется массив частей строк

```
parts = text.split('/')
```

и вы сможете выбрать нужные части

```
part1, part2 = parts[0], parts[1]
```

если же разделителей в строке много, но вы хотите взять строку до первого разделителя и строку после первого разделителя, то тут есть 2 варианта:

вариант 1:

```
pos = text.find('/')
part1 = text[:pos]
part2 = text[pos + 1:]
```

т.е. нашли первый разделитель и выделили строку до и после него

вариант 2:

использовать старый добрый `split`, но склеить оставшиеся части строк в одну:

```
parts = text.split('/')

part1 = parts[0]
part2 = '/'.join(parts[1:])
```

Comment: правильней всего будет передавать `split` ещё один параметр